# Trabalhar com datas e horários em uma tabela

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu criei um diagrama de uma academia que possui horários e dias, também criei duas tabelas no Oracle, que são essas:

```
create table dia_semana (
coddia number (6) primary key,
dia DATE);


create table horario (
codhorario number (8) primary key,
horainicio ,
horafim );
```

*Obviamente elas não estão finalizadas.*

O tipo de dado `DATE` permite a visualização de dados no formato `YYYY-MM-DD` estou correto?

Como eu faria para ele mostrar no formato brasileiro?

Eu gostaria de saber também, se existe algum datatype que imprima apenas dados no formato de hora e não data/hora, caso exista, qual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> O tipo de dado DATE permite a visualização de dados no formato
>   YYYY-MM-DD estou correto?

Sim e não, o tipo `DATE` armazena uma data no banco de dados, logo visualizar vai depender de quem está lidando com esse dado.

> Como eu faria para ele mostrar no formato brasileiro?

Você pode converter seu dado de `date` para `varchar` e mostrar o dado do jeito que quiser, basta usar a função [to_char](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

Exemplo:

```
to_char(horainicio,'dd/mm/rrrr');
```

> Eu gostaria de saber também, se existe algum datatype que imprima
>   apenas dados no formato de hora e não data/hora, caso exista, qual?

Imprimir é diferente de armazenar, mas entendo seu ponto de vista. No `Oracle` não tem como armazenar somente o horário... A menos que queira guardar essa informação em texto... daí poderia utilizar o `varchar2`, porém à uma série de desvantagens em fazer isso e eu não recomendo.

Para imprimir somente a hora, pode-se utilizar também a função `to_char`.

Exemplo:

```
to_char(horainicio,'hh24:mi');
```

Comment: Onde exatamente eu implementaria esse to_char, algo desse tipo? ```dia DATE to_char (dia, 'DD/MM/AAAA');```

Comment: No seu diagrama não vai mudar nada, continua colocando os campos de data e hora com o tipo `DATE`. Isso seria na consulta da sua tabela, através de um SELECT.